# Drupal 6 Views "No result behaviour" use a view

Tags: views, 6

With the Views module for Drupal 7 you can set a "No result behaviour" that uses another View rather than just text. I can't see the same functionality in Views 2 for Drupal 6. Is it possible to extend Views to do this?

The motivation for this is that we have a home page driven by a View that displays the recent contents from a user's groups; if the user hasn't joined any groups yet then we want to display a different View using content from all groups.

Comment: Have you tried Views 3 for Drupal 6?

Comment: We considered it, but several of the modules we're using do not work correctly with Views 3 so need to stick with 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simulate this if you instantiate the view in code.  The general steps are

1. Make a custom block.
2. In the block view callback, instantiate and execute the view you want, but don't generate output.
3. Check the number of rows.  If zero, then repeat #2 with your alternate view.
4. Generate the output for the view, and add to the block output.
5. Use the block in place of the view where you need to.

If you do everything properly, all of your view templates will be used, so you aren't really losing anything.

All of the views related function are [documented](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21views%21views.module/6) at drupalcontrib.org, but I think that is the Drupal 6, Views 3 version.  Googling on `views_get_view` will also get you started and should lead to examples of generating views with code.  If you have [Advanced Help](http://drupal.org/project/advanced_help) installed, you will also see some information there.

I have done something similar before, but I can't find the code.  I can remember, I will update the answer with some stubbed out code.